# Autohotkey | Change The Speed The Curser Drags Down

Tags: autohotkey

So, I have an .ahk script that drags the mouse down if you hold down the left mouse button. I was wondering how to change the value to it goes faster/slower and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the script used

```
    #NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

; NRA
NRA := 1

; NR
~LButton::
while GetKeyState("LButton") & NRA
{
DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, 0, int, 1, uint, 0, int, 0)
Sleep, 15
DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, 0, int, 1, uint, 0, int, 0)
Sleep, 5
}
return

; keys
Insert::ExitApp
delete::suspend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx

Second and third parameters are position, `x` and `y`.
Look at it like that:

```
DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, x, int, y, uint, 0, int, 0)
```

In your case, since you want to "drag down", you are interested in changing `y`.

So for example:

```
DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, 0, int, 5, uint, 0, int, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks!! I am also trying to change it to double, instead of int, so I can use decimals for the y value. Any idea on how I can do that?